# Avoiding loops in grepl

Tags: r, loops, grepl

I have a problem with grepl() function. Basically saying I have two tables. First one contains all possible combinations (I'm using function combinations() in library GameTheoryAllocation), second one contains all possible customer's paths and number of conversions for each path. I want to select all paths and number of their conversions from second table that contain one OR more source from the first table. For example I have "Direct" and "Natural_Search" as a combination. So I select ALL paths and conversions number that have "Direct" somewhere in path or "Natural_Search" or both at the same time.

I have already prepared the combinations table by replacing number with names of each path and putting a " | " symbol between them. And the code I wrote for this task :

```
test <- subset(clear,grepl(s$Classic[1],clear$path),select=c("path","totalCoversions"))
```

So the code works, but the problem is that it takes the first combination only. I want it to take second, third and so on (I have 1024 combinations). I was trying to put a "for" loop there but it takes too long.

"s" is the name of table with conversions (and classic is name of the column within it), clear is the table with paths.

Any ideas?

Comment: please add a snippet of your data and your expected output. You can use `dput()` for that task. This makes it easier for others to help you. Nevertheless, `paste(s$Classic[1], collapse ="|")` could help?